# Can't type in current cell after issuing setCurrentCell()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There's probably a simple explanation for this but I'm relatively new to writing functions.  I have the following function:

```
function plusCoinFlip() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E15');
  var moveTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('M30');
  cell.setValue(cell.getValue() + 1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().setCurrentCell(moveTo);
  moveTo.activate();
}
```

I have an image (added with 'insert image over cells') to which I have assigned this function.  When the image is clicked, it increments the value in cell E15 and sets the 'current' cell to M30 as expected.

However, once the function completes, when I try to type a value into the cell nothing happens.  Cell M30 is highlighted as expected, and M30 appears in the name box.  Using the arrow keys at this point does not move the active cell either.

If I hit 'enter', the *image* I clicked is highlighted instead of entering edit mode on M30 (which remains showing as the current cell), so I think somehow it is retaining focus on the image instead of the active highlighted cell.  I must manually click M30 before I can enter a value, so it's not that the cell is protected or anything, it just doesn't seem to be fully assigning focus to it like I expect.

The desire is to not have to click the cell again (which was the whole point of moving the current cell in the first place).  I did also try using setActiveSelection() as well as myRange.activate() with identical results.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

Your goal is to be able to type in a cell after the script is executed without the need of clicking the cell with your mouse.

The reason for this strange behaviour is the pop up `Finished script` message that appears after you click on the image. The message is hidden from the `ui` but you still need to escape it.

**Solution:**

There is only way to do that and that is to press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button before you type in the cell and in this way you don't need to touch your mouse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This seems like a huge miss on Google's part to not offer an option to suppress this message or design it in some other way.  Every time you have to run a function you have to click back in the spreadsheet in order to edit it again?  This is stunningly stupid and a non-starter for people who need to be productive.  Where can enhancement requests be made to address this?